# Load remote session in browser outside of console

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-device-farm

I successfully managed to create a remote session on AWS device farm using the Ruby SDK. It returns a host and a Websocket (WSS) endpoint.

I want an URL that I can load in a browser for end users to interact with the screen rather than to go through my console.

How can I achieve this?

And is there a way to send gestures (e.g. finger position, clicks) and keyboard commands through code?

Response I get from the Ruby SDK:

```
#<struct Aws::DeviceFarm::Types::GetRemoteAccessSessionResult
 remote_access_session=
  #<struct Aws::DeviceFarm::Types::RemoteAccessSession
   arn="arn:aws:devicefarm:us-west-2:123208948432:session:1232323df-ceba-4cca-bbf6-dfcdrer1232/2b169a83-19cd-4929-b26a-123287878sdf/00000",
   name="MySession",
   created=2023-05-31 08:53:44 1149239/4194304 +1000,
   status="RUNNING",
   result="PENDING",
   message=nil,
   started=nil,
   stopped=nil,
   device=
    #<struct Aws::DeviceFarm::Types::Device
     arn="arn:aws:devicefarm:us-west-2::device:9769808870C54DD798C7985DA7515A05",
     name="Apple iPhone SE (2022)",
     manufacturer="Apple",
     model="Apple iPhone SE (2022)",
     model_id="A2595",
     form_factor="PHONE",
     platform="IOS",
     os="16.4",
     cpu=#<struct Aws::DeviceFarm::Types::CPU frequency="Hz", architecture="arm64e", clock=0.0>,
     resolution=#<struct Aws::DeviceFarm::Types::Resolution width=750, height=1334>,
     heap_size=0,
     memory=64000000000,
     image="9769808870C54DD798C7985DA7515A05",
     carrier=nil,
     radio=nil,
     remote_access_enabled=true,
     remote_debug_enabled=false,
     fleet_type="PUBLIC",
     fleet_name=nil,
     instances=nil,
     availability=nil>,
   instance_arn=nil,
   remote_debug_enabled=false,
   remote_record_enabled=false,
   remote_record_app_arn=nil,
   host_address="172.19.160.61",
   client_id=nil,
   billing_method="METERED",
   device_minutes=#<struct Aws::DeviceFarm::Types::DeviceMinutes total=0.0, metered=0.0, unmetered=0.0>,
   endpoint=
    "wss://devicefarm-interactive.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/?X-Amz-Date=20230530T225629Z&X-Amz-Credential=DFSDSDFS_6712DSSDF2Fus-west-2%2Fdevicefarm%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&arn=arn%3Aaws%3Adevicefarm%3Aus-west-2%3A231231232323%3Asession%2312323df-ceba-4cca-bbf6-c7395365c948%2F2b169a83-19cd-1112-b26a-196f7796411a%2F00000&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=some_long_signature&X-Amz-Security-Token=some_long-token",
   device_udid=nil,
   interaction_mode=nil,
   skip_app_resign=nil,
   vpc_config=nil>>
```

Thank you!